# Is there any function to change the URL Path of website?

Tags: apache, http, url-rewriting

I would like to change the path of the website from http://localhost/en-in/pan
to http://localhost/en-in/individual/pan

without creating a folder individual.

Kindly let me know if there is anything.

Following is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine On example.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]



ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.example.com/404
# or map them to one error document:
# ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en-us

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]

# or map them to one error document:
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
```

Comment: Modify the part where you create your route or use some htaccess redirection maybe ?

Comment: Hi Adyson, we are using the Apache server. in the root directory we are storing all files including pan and other but for specific file I would like to add the artificial URL such that it should look like http://localhost/en-in/individual/pan instead of http://localhost/en-in/pan

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the server you are running on.
On apache, this can be achieved by creating a `.htaccess` file on your root directory of the website and add there the `Redirect` command:

```
Redirect /en-in/pan /en-in/individual/pan
```

Comment: Thanks Tomer, I have tried this but I need to attach "Individual" in the URL for specific file and not for other files.

Answer (score -1):

Create a `.htaccess` file under your base directory (public_html or www) and put the content:

```
RewriteEngine On #remove this line if it doesn't work
RewriteRule en-in/individual/pan(/?)$ en-in/pan [QSA,L]
```

Then you can redirect your traffic from active link to the new link

Comment: Hi Omi, thanks for your help, but can you please clarify that here "pan" defines a specific file name right?

Comment: yes, ``pan`` should be either an existing file or a part of an existing URL.

Comment: @AjinkyaChoube is ``http://localhost/en-in/pan`` is a dynamically generated URL or static URL (defined in .htaccess)?

Comment: this URL http://localhost/en-in/pan is not dynamically generated it is static.

Comment: @AjinkyaChoube please show your ``.htaccess`` file contents

Comment: Added .htaccess file

Comment: you have made so much mess in the .htaccess file. Duplicate ``RewriteEngine On``
and unnecessary use ``RewriteBase /en-us``

Comment: As we are redirecting customer to different application based on country we have added this

Comment: that's okay but I still don't think it's required.

Comment: ok thanks for your feedback if you find any solution please let me know